# C++ Make compile errors with Poco Library - Path Name containing spaces

Tags: c++, unix, escaping, makefile, poco

I'm attempting to build/install/use the Poco C++ Libraries. I'm running Ubututu (Natty). I've compiled the static libraries which are working fine, but when I set the env var PROJECT_BASE to a path containing spaces, I get errors:

```
make
/bin/sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
/bin/sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
/home/username/Documents/poco-1.4.1p1/build/rules/global:62: *** Current working directory not under $PROJECT_BASE. Stop.
```

I've set PROJECT_BASE to:

```
/files/Dropbox/Myname\'s\ Work/C++\ Work
```

which I believe should be escaped correctly? Adding a trailling backspace gives me the alternate error of:

```
make
/bin/sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
awk: line 1: runaway string constant "/files/Dro ...
/home/username/Documents/poco-1.4.1p1/build/rules/global:62: *** Current working directory not under $PROJECT_BASE. Stop.
```

I might be missing something basic, but I've been wrestling for a few days now to get the Poco C++ Library build system set up how I want it to no avail :S I know the README said something about SYMBLINKS screwing up the PROJECT_BASE, but I'm no using any :S /files is an ext4 mount (same hdd, seperate partition) if that's relevant at all.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Paths containing quote characters and/or spaces are often handled incorrectly in shell scripts - you'll make your life a lot easier by simply avoiding them

Comment: Perhaps just file the bug ? The makefile is likely borked somewhere

Comment: hmm yeah, at this rate I might just swap to using a different c++ library :P I get the impression that Poco isn't widely used/supported. I'm reluctant to rename directories to remove spaces on my dropbox because it'll sync to 3 other places and most likely conflict/duplicate loads of files :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires great care and deliberate effort to make systems such as makefiles handle pathnames with spaces accurately.  It can be done; it is not trivial.  It is fairly clear that this package has not been so modified; it is like the majority of such packages.

If you really want to make life hell for yourself, use a pathname such as:

```
/home/mine/He said, "Don't do it!"/poco-1.4.1
```

Spaces, single and double quotes -- at least it doesn't include backquotes, dollars, parentheses, newlines, etc.

In the meantime, bow to the inevitable - use a pathname without spaces etc in it.

Comment: ahaha had a feeling this may be the case :) Normally my solution would be to use a symblink to convert the path to a nicer one to work with...however is it possible to mount a subdirectory to a different place in unix? aka mount /files/path with silly spaces in/ /nicerpath ? - thanks for the reply though :)

Comment: @Technosites: I don't think it is possible to avoid the spaces with `mount` as suggested.  Using a symlink without spaces in the name should work.  Aim to keep to the POSIX [portable filename character set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_276).

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else getting the: "*** Current working directory not under $PROJECT_BASE. Stop." error, I found a solution that maybe sounds obscure.

Basically, if any of the parent directories are symlinks, it will generate this error.

> IMPORTANT: Make sure that the path to the build directory does not
>   contain symbolic links. Furthermore, on Mac OS X (or other systems
>   with case insensitive filesystems), make sure that the characters in
>   the path have the correct case. Otherwise you'll get an error saying
>   "Current working directory not under $PROJECT_BASE.".

http://pocoproject.org/docs/00200-GettingStarted.html

In my case, I was compiling the library 5 levels deep and the second directory was a symlink. Changing it to a directory resolved the issue.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is not with symlinks, as in my case, you probably are not specifying a full path, but instead a relative one, as indicated in the following blog post.

http://fatalfeel.blogspot.com/2013/09/poco-with-cocos2d-in-android-and-ios.html